# Config angularfire2 and firebase to angular-seed

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angular5

I just clone project angular-seed and I was trying to config AngularFire2 and Firebase to my project.

when I run locally I got following error

> "Fetch API cannot load npm:node_modules/angularfire2/bundles/core.umd.js. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request."

and if I try to run to production I got

> [10:02:03] 'build.bundles.app' errored after 1.1 s
>   [10:02:03] Error on fetch for npm:node_modules/angularfire2/bundles/core.umd.js at file://../angular-seed/node_modules/npm:node_modules/angularfire2/bundles/core.umd.js
>           Loading dist/tmp/app/app.module.js
>           Loading dist/tmp/app/main.js
>           Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../angular-seed/node_modules/npm:node_modules/angularfire2/bundles/core.umd.js'
>   [10:02:03] 'build.prod' errored after 5.4 s

```
settings:

seed.config.ts:

    paths: {
      ...

      'firebase': 'npm:node_modules/firebase',
      'angularfire2': 'npm:node_modules/angularfire2',
      ...
    },
    packages: { ...
    firebase: { 
      defaultExtension: 'js', 
      main: 'firebase.js' 

    },
    angularfire2: {
      main: 'bundles/core.umd.js', 
      defaultExtension: 'js' 
    }
    ... }



angularfire2: 5.0.0-rc.4

firebase: 4.8.2
```

Any idea what could solve the problem?